# Failure of solving trajectory optimization use Snopt in drake, how to fix it?

Tags: optimization, drake

I am trying to solve a trajectory optimization task in **Drake** and access initial guesses randomly. I found that if the initial guesses is not good enough then the solving procedure will fail and report a **resource problem** as the **picture below**. How do I allocate more storage for that resource? I have try to allocate more through optional parameter "**Total integer workspace**", but it doesn't work. Is there any body tell me how to allocate more relative storage for Snopt in Drake? If it can't be set manually, what can I do when this occurs?

Thanks !

[snopt.out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQffF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the options through `SetSolverOption`

```cc
prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver::id(), "Total integer workspace", 100000);
prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver::id(), "User integer workspace", 100000);
```

to change the default workspace size in SNOPT. For more information on setting solver options, please refer to the tutorial https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/solver_parameters.ipynb

Comment: THANKS for answer!
I have follows the commands, but it doesn't seem to work:
1. I can't find any parameter changed in log file snopt.out as I set "Major feasibility tolerance";
2. Solving still failed for the same reason, but the magnitude of lack storage has a very small change, e.g., 1969563-->1960807 ;
I think some options can be changed but wouldn't show in log file due to the print level of Snopt, right?
Additionally, I post the debug process of "Total integer workspace"&"User integer workspace" in the follow  link (coming soon), please help me, THANKS!!