# Solving error of Snopt in drake, how to fix it?

Tags: optimization, drake

This question follows previous [Failure of solving trajectory optimization use Snopt in drake, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245808/failure-of-solving-trajectory-optimization-use-snopt-in-drake-how-to-fix-it) and Thanks Dai!
I met an error with a lack of storage when I tried to solve a nonlinear program using Snopt. Error information is shown in the follow picture: [Original error information from snopt.out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlBEZ.png)

Then I use the followed command:
`prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver::id(), "Total integer workspace", 100000);`
`prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver::id(), "User integer workspace", 100000);`
and it still failed with the same reason but the magnitude is little smaller, e.g. option "Total integer workspace" from 1969563 to 1960807.[Error information screenshoot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU6Da.png)

As it does affect the magnitude so I set a larger "Total integer workspace" and "User integer workspace". The results of attempts are shown in follows:
`Total integer workspace=200000,User integer workspace=200000`==>[Error information 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sufGW.png)
`Total integer workspace=300000,User integer workspace=300000`==>[Error information 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8L6o.png)
`Total integer workspace=400000,User integer workspace=400000`==>[Error information 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOPo9.png)
`Total integer workspace=500000,User integer workspace=500000`==>[Error information 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piOuE.png)
`Total integer workspace=500000,User integer workspace=600000`==>[Error information 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH3LI.png)
`Total integer workspace=700000,User integer workspace=700000`==>[Error information 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtX80.png)
`Total integer workspace=800000,User integer workspace=800000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJRfT.png
`Total integer workspace=800000,User integer workspace=900000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/AblUc.png
`Total integer workspace=1000000,User integer workspace=1000000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3gX.png
`Total integer workspace=1010000,User integer workspace=1010000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/pufBK.png
`Total integer workspace=1020000,User integer workspace=1020000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/biThe.png
There are some additional test may help:
`Total integer workspace=900000,User integer workspace=1000000`==>https://i.stack.imgur.com/NilNy.png
**I am sorry for the strange format of picture above, because my reputation can only support up to 8 picture links.T_T T_T**
All of these tests have same initial guess. I found that when I was increasing both "Total integer workspace" and "User integer workspace" from 100000 to 600000, the magnitude of lacking storage first get smaller and then get bigger. When I set the two options bigger than 800000, the error type has changed for something become abnormal.
NOW I am struggling with these questions that:
1.Why the magnitude of lacking storage changing strangely?
2.What should I do about this situation?
3.Does the initial guess matter whether it can get a feasible solution no matter how we adjust the storage?
4.How to determine whether an initial guess is reasonable?
5.How do I set "Total integer workspace" and "User integer workspace" when this storage error occurs? In other words, what is the debug flow when we have problems that reasonability of initial guess, storage error, feasibility of constraints and other problems are coupled together?

Warmest Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you have checked out Drake with its source code? Could you try to modify these two lines https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/0cdb1793b303796484f3af11d1d585bc76ffdedc/solvers/snopt_solver.cc#L303-L304 to increase the storage to a larger number, and then recompile Drake together with your problem?

Comment: Thanks, I am just reading the code. I will try according to your suggestion. But what value should I set teem to? Is it the same as recommended in the log? And are they must have same value?

Comment: @cby Hi, did you manage to solve the problem??

Comment: @HongkaiDai I tried modifying those 2 lines, however it seems since I'm compiling from source, I am no longer able to use the SNOPT solver...

Comment: @Rufus Right to use the source version of SNOPT you will need a SNOPT license. You can get a student license or ask the SNOPT authors for purchasing. The binary version of Drake can use SNOPT for free, but not the source version of Drake.